# Is there a way to avoid inexact results when using linear algebra with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to run the following code, which is simple matrix algebra:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg

A = np.array([[1,2],[1,-1],[1,1]])
b = np.array([[1],[-1],[5]])

r = linalg.inv(A.transpose()@A)@A.transpose()@b

print(r)
```

The output I obtain is:

```
[[1.]
[1.]]
```

However, I'm expecting a strict `[[1],[1]]`, which is what I obtain when doing the calculation by hand. Doing further operations with `r` in this form starts giving me incorrect results, for example, if I compute `A@r` I obtain:

```
[[3.00000000e+00]
 [3.33066907e-16]
 [2.00000000e+00]]
```

Instead of the expected `[[3],[0],[2]]`. Is there another way to do matrix algebra to avoid this issue, maybe having python use fractions instead of raw computing for taking the inverse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does numpy.linalg.solve() offer more precise matrix inversions than numpy.linalg.inv()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256252/why-does-numpy-linalg-solve-offer-more-precise-matrix-inversions-than-numpy-li)

Comment: @Kaia ideally, I'd like to use the inverse operation to confirm whether my hand calculations are correct, instead of solving for an unknown variable. I don't know whether that's possible. That's why I'm not sure the linked question answers my question, since it involves using `np.linalg.solve(A, b)` instead

Comment: If you want to do exact rational arithmetic you'll have to use something like sympy and make a matrix over the rationals.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I found out just now, sympy gives me exact results. Thank you for the answer! Should I delete this question, or would you like to post the sympy suggestion? it might be of use for someone else wanting linear algebra over rational numbers

Comment: Even better, just answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it is better to do matrix algebra with the sympy library for this case. We get our desired (and more readable) result with:

```
import sympy as sy

A = sy.Matrix([[1,2],[1,-1],[1,1]])
b = sy.Matrix([[1],[-1],[5]])

r = (A.T*A)**-1*A.T*b

print(r)
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs due to floating-point number imprecision. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-error-in-python/) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer found through looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898233/solving-linear-system-over-integers-with-numpy).

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg

A = np.array([[1,2],[1,-1],[1,1]])
b = np.array([[1],[-1],[5]])

r = linalg.inv(A.transpose()@A)@A.transpose()@b

print(r.round().astype(int))
print(A@r.round().astype(int))
```

EDIT: The above answers the question using `numpy` (which the OP asked for). However, it is better to use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) but it looks like `numpy` [does not support `decimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770870/are-decimal-dtypes-available-in-numpy?noredirect=1&lq=1), but [`pandas` can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094820/how-to-create-pandas-series-with-decimal).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but do we not risk getting inexact results if we actually have fractions in our computations? It seems your approach would round rational numbers